# Summing columns of characters in R data frame to create a new column

Tags: r

I currently have a data frame in R, where each entry is a character. However, each character also corresponds to a point value, where: `B = 10`, `S = 1`, `C = 1`, `X = 0`.

For example, consider the following data frame

```
> df = data.frame(p1 = c("B", "B", "C", "C", "S", "S", "X"), p2 = c("X", "B", "B", "S", "C", "S", "X"), p3 = c("C", "B", "B", "X", "C", "S", "X"))
> df
  p1 p2 p3
1  B  X  C
2  B  B  B
3  C  B  B
4  C  S  X
5  S  C  C
6  S  S  S
7  X  X  X
```

I want to create three new columns in R: `c1`, `c2`, `c3` where these are essentially the "lagged" sum (using the numeric values of each characters) of the `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` values.

```
  p1 p2 p3 c1 c2 c3
1  B  X  C 0  10 10
2  B  B  B 0  10 20
3  C  B  B 0  1  11
4  C  S  X 0  1  2
5  S  C  C 0  1  2
6  S  S  S 0  1  2
7  X  X  X 0  0  0
```

For example, `c1` is always initialized to 0. `c2` will be the point value of `p1`, and `c3` will be the sum of `c2` and the point value of `p1`.

In general `c_i = c_{i-1} + p_{i-1}`.

Is there an easy way to do this in R? Thank you in advance, as I am a relatively novice R user.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work.  `matchFun` is a function that does the matching.

```
matchFun <- function(x) c(10, 1, 1, 0)[x]

within(df, {
    c3 <- rowSums(sapply(list(p1, p2), matchFun))
    c2 <- matchFun(p1)
    c1 <- 0L
})
#   p1 p2 p3 c1 c2 c3
# 1  B  X  C  0 10 10
# 2  B  B  B  0 10 20
# 3  C  B  B  0  1 11
# 4  C  S  X  0  1  2
# 5  S  C  C  0  1  2
# 6  S  S  S  0  1  2
# 7  X  X  X  0  0  0
```

Comment: Since `x` to `matchFun` is always a factor, `c(10, 1, 1, 0)[x]` should be sufficient and fast.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelLawrence.  Doesn't that assume the order of `p1` though?

Comment: The factors will have lexicographically sorted levels, which are indexed by integers. The only gotcha is if all variables do not have the same level sets.